# Positivity of real functions in two variables

Tags: real-analysis, gn.general-topology, polynomials, inequalities, real-algebraic-geometry

Assume that $f_0,f_1,f_2$ are polynomial functions of degree two in two variables. This means that the $f_i$ are linear combinations with real coefficients of $x^2,xy,x,y^2,y,1$.

Consider the function $f = f_1^2-af_0f_2:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ where $a\in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$. Is it true that for a "random" choice (whit a suitable definition of random) of the $f_i$ there exists $(x_0,y_0)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $f(x_0,y_0) \geq 0$.

Clearly, this does not hold for any choice of the $f_i$. Take for instance $f_1\equiv 0$, $f_0 = x^2+1$, $f_2 = y^2+1$. Then $f(x,y) = -a(x^2y^2+x^2+y^2+1) < 0 $ for all $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2$.

Write
$$f_0 = a_1 x^2 + a_2xy+ a_3 x+ a_4 y^2+ a_5 y+ a_6;$$
$$f_1 = b_1 x^2 + b_2xy+ b_3 x+ b_4 y^2+ b_5 y+ b_6;$$
$$f_2 = c_1 x^2 + c_2xy+ c_3 x+ c_4 y^2+ c_5 y+ c_6;$$
Then $f$ corresponds to the point $(a_1,\dots,c_6)\in\mathbb{R}^{18}$.

Taking
$$f_0 = \epsilon_0(x^2 + y^2 + 1);$$
$$f_1 = \epsilon_1(x^2 + y^2 + 1);$$
$$f_2 = \epsilon_2(x^2 + y^2 + 1);$$
we have $f = (\epsilon_0^2-a\epsilon_1\epsilon_2)(x^2 + y^2 + 1)$ which is always negative when $\epsilon_0^2-a\epsilon_1\epsilon_2 < 0$.

But the point $(f_0,f_1,f_2)$ lies inside the linear subspace $a_2 = a_3 = a_5 = b_2 = b_3 = b_5 = c_2 = c_3 = c_5 = 0$.

Thank you very much.

Comment: It is unclear what you mean by 'for a "random" choice': Do you mean with probability $1$ or with a nonzero probability? Also, it is unclear what you mean by "a suitable definition of random": what would be suitable for you and what would be not -- that should be clearly specified, using appropriate quantifiers. As your own example suggests, some definitions of random would be unsuitable **to you**. On MathOverflow, you should be specific enough so that it be quite clear what constitutes an answer to your question and what does not.

Comment: "Random" would be the following: each $f_i$ depends on $6$ real parameters, so we can see the triple $(f_0,f_1,f_2)$ as a point in $\mathbb{R}^{18}$. There is a subset of the form $S = \{G_1 = \dots = G_r = 0\}\subset\mathbb{R}^{18}$, where the $G_i$ are functions of the coefficients of the $f_i$, such that for all $(f_0,f_1,f_2) \in\mathbb{R}^{18}\setminus S$ we have that $f(x_0,y_0)\geq 0$ for some $(x_0,y_0)\in\mathbb{R}^2$. I guess that from the probabilistic point of view this implies that the property I am requiring holds with probability $1$.

Comment: Well, then clearly without loss of generality $r=1$. Also, are the $G_i$'s to be (piecewise-)smooth? If so, the answer is no: Take e.g. $a>1$ and $f_0,f_1,f_2$ each close enough to $x^2+y^2+1$.

Comment: I addressed your example in the new version of the question. I think the $G_i$ could be simply polynomials. For instance the $f_0,f_1,f_2$ in your example are all inside the zero locus of $9$ linear polynomials.

Comment: This does not address what I proposed. I said "close enough". not "proportional to". That is, what I proposed is $f_i=a_{i,0}+a_{i,1}x+a_{i,2}y+a_{i,3}xy+a_{i,4}x^2+a_{i,5}y^2$ for $i=0,1,2$, with $(a_{i,0},a_{i,1},a_{i,2},a_{i,3},a_{i,4},a_{i,5})$ close to $(1,0,0,0,1,1)$ for each $i=0,1,2$. The set of such triples $(f_0,f_1,f_2)$ contains a nonempty $18$-dimensional open ball.

Comment: I got it. You are definitely right. Do you think it could be possible to characterize the set one has to remove from $\mathbb{R}^{18}$ for the positivity property I required to hold?

Comment: I am not sure if such a characterization is possible (except for a tautological one). Yet, you may want to post the characterization question separately, possibly elsewhere.

Comment: Do you have a further response to the answer below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand\R{\mathbb R}\newcommand\c{\mathsf c}\newcommand\ep{\varepsilon}$The answer is no. Indeed, after clarifications given by the OP in comments and in the original post, the question can be stated as follows:

> For $i=0,1,2$, let
> $$f_i(x,y)=a_{i,0}+a_{i,1}x+a_{i,2}y+a_{i,3}xy+a_{i,4}x^2+a_{i,5}y^2,$$
> where the $a_{i,j}$ are real numbers.
> For a real $a>0$, let $M_a$ be the set of all matrices $(a_{i,j}\colon i=0,1,2,\,j=0,\dots,5)\in\R^{3\times6}$ such that $f(x,y):=f_1(x,y)^2-af_0(x,y)f_2(x,y)\ge0$ for some $(x,y)\in\R^2$.
> Is it true that the dimension (in whatever appropriate sense) of the complement $M_a^\c$ of $M_a$ to $\R^{3\times6}$ is strictly less that $18$ (the dimension of $\R^{3\times6}$)?

Let $g(x,y):=1+x^2+y^2$. For real $\ep>0$, let $N_\ep$ denote the set of all matrices $(a_{i,j}\colon i=0,1,2,\,j=0,\dots,5)\in\R^{3\times6}$ such that
$|a_{i,j}-b_j|<\ep$ for all $i=0,1,2,\,j=0,\dots,5$, where $(b_0,\dots,b_5)=(1,0,0,0,1,1)$. Then for $i=0,1,2$ and all real $x,y$ we have
$$|f_i(x,y)-g(x,y)|<\ep(1+|x|+|y|+|xy|+x^2+y^2)
\le2\ep g(x,y),$$
since $|x|\le(1+x^2)/2$, $|y|\le(1+y^2)/2$, and $|xy|\le(x^2+y^2)/2$.

So, taking now any $a\in(1,2)$ and any $\ep\in(0,\frac{\sqrt a-1}{2(\sqrt a+1)})$, we get ($\ep<1/2$ and) for all real $x,y$
$$f_1(x,y)^2-af_0(x,y)f_2(x,y)\le g(x,y)^2[(1+2\ep)^2-a(1-2\ep)^2]<0.$$
So, $N_\ep\subseteq M_a^\c$ and the dimension of $N_\ep$ is $18$. Thus, the dimension of $M_a^\c$ is $18$, not $<18$.